# What is normalized angular frequency?

Tags: sampling, frequency

I am new to DSP, and I am self-studying. I came upon this question, and I am stuck at it. Could someone please help me? Here is the question:

> In order to digitally create a sinusoid with frequency $f$ = 440 Hz, you
>   will need the normalized angular frequency $\omega$. How large is $\omega$
>   for a sampling frequency $f_s$ = 16 kHz?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

1. Determine the argument of a *continuous-time* sinusoid with frequency $f=440$ Hz.
2. Sample that continuous-time sinusoid by replacing $t$ by $nT$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, with $T=1/f_s$ being the interval between samples.

This gives you an expression $\sin(n\omega_0)$, where $\omega_0$ depends on $f$ and $f_s$. $\omega_0$ is the normalized angular frequency.